# prevent navigationBar with largeTitles from collapsing when user scrolls swift4/xcode9/ios11

Tags: ios11, navigationbar, xcode9, swift4

I want to prevent the new largeTitles navigationBar from collapsing into a standard small navigationBar when the user scrolls content.  i.e. always keep the navigationBar large size with title in large font.

The reason I want to do this is that I have a segmentedControl in the navigationBar above the title exactly like in the iOS phone missed calls page.  Except that I always want the title and segmented control to appear.  I don't want the title to disappear when the user scrolls.

Is there any default behavior that can keep the new large navigationBar from collapsing when the user scrolls?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little late but it might be useful to somebody:

If you add a scrollView (tableView, collectionView) directly to your viewControllers view, the large title will expand and collapse.

If you add any other non-scrolling view **before** adding the scrollView, the largeTitle will stay expanded.

i ended up doing something like

```
let view = UIView()
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

self.view.addSubview(view)
view.pinToEdgesOfSuperview()

self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
self.tableView.pinToEdgesOfSuperview()
```

Not the most beautiful solution but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

## iOS 11+

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

Should do the trick.